# ReactJS: Show custom element name in html

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I rendered the following react element

```
<CustomElement />
```

let's say that CustomElement - is rendered as

```
<div>somethingelse</div>
```

In HTML I'll see `<div>somethingelse</div>`

**Question**: Is there a way to display `<div-CustomElement>somethingelse</div-CustomElement>`
Or something similar, **I've heard that it's possible but didn't find a way to do this**.

P.S. *I'm not talking about setting class names or this kind of stuff for recognizing the element. I'm talking about the element name itself to be displayed as a custom element.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a custom html tag and it will show up in the DOM tree:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div-CustomElement>Hello React</div-CustomElement>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Here is a demo: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/xEqLzr and here you can inspect it easily with dev tools: http://s.codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/debug/xEqLzr

Comment: Well I'll be damned... it just worked oO. Now I wonder how he knows which html properties such cutomer elements default to

Comment: Shit that’s crazy. I was trying I was trying all these weird hacky ways and React 16 dropped the InjectDomNode (whatever it’s called)

Answer (score 2):

You may used 'document.registerElement('div-CustomElement', reactClass)' for creating own custom tag as html.

For more information you can check this [link](https://addyosmani.com/blog/component-interop-with-react-and-custom-elements/)

Comment: Thanks. it's useful however I was looking for a native reactjs way without installing third parties